# Reactのrender()内で値の文字列結合をするときの書き方が不明です

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    render() {
    let tags = this.props.tags;
    if (!Array.isArray(this.props.tags)) {
        tags = [tags];
    }
    let tagsDisplayName = "name";
    if(tags.length > 0){
        const category = tags[0].category;
        if(category === "product" || category === "samplecode"){
            tagsDisplayName = "name" + "description"// NG（値に何も表示されない）
            tagsDisplayName = "name"                // OK（nameの値が表示される）
        }
    }

    return (
        <div style={this.props.style}>
            <span>{this.state.error}</span>
            <TagsInput
                〜省略〜
                tagDisplayProp={tagsDisplayName}
                〜省略〜
```

Answer (score 0):

どういう意図での質問なのかいまいち分かりづらいのですが
文字列の結合でしたらテンプレート文字列を使うとよいかと思います。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

`${tagsDisplayName}description`